# Oracle shows "no data found" when I try to retrieve data from existing column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-xe

I have created `DriversTable` that stores details like Name, Age, Gender etc as shown in the screenshots below.

When I try to retrieve data in a row based on the `Availability` column that exists in the `DriversTable`, it says "no data found".

But when I try to retrieve data based on the `Gender` column, it shows the result as expected

I don't know why this is happening, is it some kind of exception in database or am I doing something wrong ?

Please help

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the **datatype** of your `Availability` column? You should really **show us** the structure of your table - what columns, what datatypes, what constraints?

Comment: its varchar2 the same for gender column too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be caused by columns having "hidden" characters.  Often these are spaces at the end of the value.

To test this, use `LIKE`:

```
where availability like 'Availability%'
```

If this occurs, then there are probably spaces (but there could be something else).  The most common issue is that a column is declared using `CHAR()` rather than `VARCHAR2()`.